# unable to use bib file in ~/Library/texmf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, mactex, macos

I have a `Zotero.bib` folder in my local texmf folder `/Users/jumpdiffusion/Library/texmf`. Somehow kpsewhich is not able to locate that bib file. Here is a terminal session with outputs.

```bash
work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMF
{{}/Users/jumpdiffusion/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-config,/Users/jumpdiffusion/Library/texlive/2022/texmf-var,/Users/jumpdiffusion/Library/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}

work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local

work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME
/Users/jumpdiffusion/Library/texmf

work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ ll ~/Library/texmf
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 jumpdiffusion  staff    96B Oct 28 11:49 bib/
-rw-r--r--  1 jumpdiffusion  staff   110B Oct 28 13:34 ls-R

work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ ll ~/Library/texmf/bib
total 680
-rw-------@ 1 jumpdiffusion  staff   339K Oct 28 11:49 Zotero.bib

work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ ll
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 jumpdiffusion  staff     0B Oct 28 13:22 test_bib.bbl
-rw-r--r--  1 jumpdiffusion  staff   2.2K Oct 28 13:35 test_bib.run.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 jumpdiffusion  staff   391B Oct 28 13:23 test_bib.tex

work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ kpsewhich Zotero.bib

work/tmp/test_biblatex
❯ # no output from previous command
```

As a result of this, I am not able to get bibtex working on this sample

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{Zotero.bib}
%\bibliogrpahy{Zotero}

\title{testing zotero bib}
\author{jd}
\date{\today}
%created on oct 28, 2022

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{equation}
    \exp(i\pi) + 1 = 0
\end{equation}

\cite{abbott2015understanding}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I using latest MacTeX on a M1 Mac mini.

Comment: You should never do `mktexlsr` on the personal tree. Remove the `ls-R` files.

Comment: I ran `texhash ~/Library/texmf`, which in turn ran `mktexlsr`..,

Comment: @egreg I removed the `ls-R` file, I dont understand what it does, just assumed that running `texhash` would make it visible to `latexmk`

Comment: The bib file should be placed in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib` or sub-directories of that directory. You should NOT generate an `ls-R`.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Nice catch! This was the issue. Once I have the right directory structure,  ie, all bib files should be in  `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib` issue was solved.

Comment: @HerbSchulz if you add an answer, I will accept it. thanks for solving my issue. Also added an answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the TeX Live installed by MacTeX the root of the personal tree is `~/Library/texmf`. Once that is created you must place personal files in the standard TeX Live tree structure. So `(bib|bst)` files go into `bibtex/(bib|bst}` sub-directories respectively (or sub-directories of shose directories). Personal package (sty) and class (cls) files should go in the `tex/latex/` sub-directory or sub-directgories of that directory.

You can get more information about the TeX Live installed by MacTeX in `/Applications/TeX/Documents/What is Installed.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably ran `texhash ~/Library/texmf`, which is wrong. The “personal tree” is supposed to be populated quite frequently and to be not very big. If you use `texhash` (or `mktexlsr`, which is the more modern name), you must run it *every time* you add a file.

You can note that some trees in the output of `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMF` are not preceded by `!!`: they're those where no `ls-R` file should appear and on which `texhash` or `mktexlsr` should never be run.

Just for information, the file `ls-R` is produced by `texhash`, by the way. If a program linked with the `kpse` library finds it at the top of a tree, it uses it for file lookup and this seems to be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself, based on Herb Schulz's comment below the question. The `.bib` files should be placed in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib`. Now the bib file is visible to latex, xelatex etc.

My mistake was keeping the `.bib` files in `~/Library/texmf/bib`.